# Get Prolog DCG arguments generated from sentence being parsed

Tags: parsing, prolog, lexical-analysis, dcg

I'm putting together a lexer/parser for a simple programming language using a Prolog DCG that builds up the list of tokens/syntax tree using DCG arguments, e.g.

```
symbol(semicolon) --> ";".
symbol(if) --> "if".
```

and then the syntax tree is built using those arguments to the DCG rules.

However, I've hit a bump in that when it gets to parsing variables and numbers (only integers in this language), I need the DCG arguments to be more dynamic, e.g.

```
symbol(number(X)) --> X, {integer(N)}.
```

Essentially, I need the DCG argument to essentially be generated from what it's actually parsing. Is there a way to do this? If not, what could be a good workaround?

EDIT: As a specific example, I've got the rule

```
symbol(num(N)) --> {number_codes(N,C)}, C.
```

and I need the output `N=7` when querying `phrase(symbol(num(N)),"7").`

Comment: It is definitely possible; have you seen [dcg/basics](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/dcg/basics.pl)? (Also, the source code for it [is pretty instructive too](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/dcg/basics.pl?show=src#integer/3).)

Comment: You're close. `symbol(number(X)) --> [X], {integer(X)}.` Although you want to be careful since `number/1` is a standard Prolog predicate. Perhaps pick something else.

Comment: I'm not so sure though; the specific example I'm facing at the moment is:
    `symbol(num(N)) --> {number_codes(N,C)}, C`.
I essentially need the output `N=7` when inputting `phrase(symbol(num(N)),"7").

Answer (score 1):

I see three problems here.

1. `phrase/2` wants to operate on lists of codes. Since version 7, SWI has a native string type that does not support DCGs. So, you must now resort to this slightly inconvenient formulation:

   ```
   atom_codes("if", Codes), phrase(symbol(X), Codes)
   ```
2. In general, you want to peel off something from the input *and then* hand it to some pure-Prolog predicate to do something. In other words, something like this:

   ```
   symbol(num(N)) --> [C], { number_codes(N, [C]) }.

   ?- atom_codes(9, X), phrase(symbol(S), X).
   X = [57],
   S = num(9).
   ```

   This will, of course, only work for single-digit numbers, which probably isn't what you want, so...
3. You should probably use the code from [`dcg/basics.pl`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/dcg/basics.pl) like this:

   ```
   :- use_module(library(dcg/basics)).

   symbol(num(N)) --> integer(N).

   ?- atom_codes(973, X), phrase(symbol(S), X).
   X = [57, 55, 51],
   S = num(973).
   ```

   Or you could do a copy/paste thing using [the source code](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/dcg/basics.pl?show=src#integer/3). You'll probably notice that all the DCG rules in there either start with a call to another DCG rule or they consume some of the input and then do something else; you probably don't want to generate something and then look for it in the input.